# Can I modify outgoing packets so they leave my raspberry pi from different interfaces?

Tags: python, scapy, netfilter

As part of my project I need to modify outgoing packets from my raspberry pi.
I have some code that sends udp packets to an external server, but I want to be able to modify these packets so that some are sent from ethernet and some are sent over wifi.
Is there any way to do this using Scapy and NFQUEUE?